# Unable to start plasmashell in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, desktop-environment, plasma, kde5

KWin is displaying windows, but the background, panel et cetera are missing. I tried starting plasmashell from Konsole using

```
kstart5 plasmashell
```

But it returns an error message:

```
starting invalid corona "org.kde.plasma.desktop"
```

I've tried reinstalling plasma, but it did not work. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reinstalling plasma-desktop plasma-workspace plasma-framework